# Infinite redirect loop issue htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect from one url to another using a htaccess file. I have got them all working except from one which causes an infinite redirect loop. The url I wish to redirect from is:

http://website.co.uk/author/ and i want to redirect to http://website.co.uk/author/authorname

Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Can you post the appropriate part of your .htaccess file for us to review?

Comment: always show what you've tried, otherwise its like asking us to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like your .htaccess redirect rules are doing pattern matching on your domain name, so that when you redirect to `/jamescrawford` it matches against `www.pragencyone.co.uk/author/` and tries to redirect again.

If you're trying to catch everything that matches `http://www.pragencyone.co.uk/author/.*` then you'll need to exclude `http://www.pragencyone.co.uk/author/jamescrawford` (and potentially any assets it uses like images, if they're in the same directory) from being matched by the pattern you're using.

You might try posting the actual rules that you're using to do the redirect, though obviously be sure not to post anything any info from your .htaccess that would compromise your server's security.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 AddDefaultCharset On
 Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

 RewriteRule ^author /author/jamescrawford [L]
 RewriteRule ^author/ /author/jamescrawford [L]
```